# XSL value-of returns no match

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Alright I am trying to convert an XHTML document to RDF/XML (don't ask, it's an assignment) using XSLT where the information for the RDF file is located in meta tags in the XHTML document. I have my first XPath query done to locate the value of the `about` attribute of `<rdf:Description>`. I tested the XPath query on a separate website where it returned the proper result. However, when I try to incorporate it in my XSLT the result is an empty string.

I'm just looking for a nudge in the right direction. I don't see where I'm wrong. Here's the example XHTML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="TN6_Q6.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <link rel="schema.DC" href="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" />
    <meta name="DC.title" content="le titre de mon document" />
    ...
    <title>...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

That's the XSLT I have built so far. I know it looks awful but again... that's the assignment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:template match="*">
<html><body><pre>
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?&gt;
&lt;rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" &gt;
&lt;rdf:Description rdf:about="

  <!-- THIS LINE -->
  <xsl:value-of select="html/*[local-name()='head']/*[local-name()='link']/@href"/>"&gt;

&lt;/rdf:Description&gt;
&lt;/rdf:RDF&gt;
</pre></body></html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can test the XPath right here:
http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/85785aab-0449-472e-a94f-77ee49d4e330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template matches `"*"` so the context node when that `value-of` is evaluated will be the root `html` element.  Therefore you only need to start the path from `head`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='head']/*[local-name()='link']/@href"/>
```

Or better than the `local-name()` trick would be to use the fact that you've declared the namespace in the `<xsl:stylesheet>` and use the corresponding qualified names in the path:

```
<xsl:value-of select="xhtml:head/xhtml:link/@href" />
```

You might also consider changing the template to be `match="/"` instead of `match="*"`, in which case the context would be the document root node rather than the `html` element, so you would need to add the `html` to the front of the path:

```
<xsl:value-of select="xhtml:html/xhtml:head/xhtml:link/@href" />
```

Comment: You're right about the last part. I was trying to be too generic about it but I can in fact assume that the document provided will be XHTML. I could not make it work but I will test a few more things.

Comment: Yes ! That last edit did it. Changing "*" to "/" was the solution ! Thank you so much. I will accept in 5 minutes when it is enabled.